# Jetpack Compose Instantiate a Class from Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I have my following logic class

```
class Logic(){
    private val state: MyViewModel = MyViewModel()

    
    @Composable
    fun PublicComposable(){
      Text("My public composable")
    }

    
    fun setSomething(value:String){
      state.setSomething(value)
    }

    fun getSomething(){
      return state.getSomething()
    }
}
```

I have my ViewModel which should not be accessible to the UI but only to the Logic class

```
class MyViewModel():ViewModel(){

    private val _capturedCard: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("Intial Value")
    val capturedCard: LiveData<String> = _capturedCard

    fun setSomething(value:String){
      _capturedCard.value = value
    }

    fun getSomething():String{
      return capturedCard.value
    }

}
```

Then I have my composable which I call as follows:

```
@Composable
fun Content(){
    val myclass = Logic()
    myclass.PublicComposable()

    Text("Updated Value")

    Button(onClick = {myclass.setSomething("New Value")}){
      Text("Set Something")
    }

    Text("${myclass.getSomething()}")
```

`Output`

```
Text("Initial Value")

Instead of 

Text("New Value")
```

What am I doing wrong here because I don't want the view model to be available on the compose app ui but to be present on the Logic() class only.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here" -- you are hiding your `State`, such that `Content()` cannot react to its changes. Remove `getSomething()`, have `Logic` expose a `State` for your text, and have `Content()` `remember` that `State`.

Comment: how do i do that please?

Comment: Okay i changed the state from private to public and its working but what if i want to make it private and still access the changes